# Hacking the import statement to extend an inherited class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

In a library that I wish to extend without modifying its code, several classes inherit from the same imported one. That is in this `BaseClass` I would need to overwrite a specific method.

- In the library :

```js
import { BaseClass } from './base_class';
export class ClassA extends BaseClass {}

import { BaseClass } from './base_class';
export class ClassB extends BaseClass {}
…
```

- In the external extension I wish to write :

```js
import { BaseClass } from 'library';
export class ExtendedBaseClass extends BaseClass {
    oneMethod() {
         const data = BaseClass.prototype.oneMethod.call(this);
         // make additional things with data
         return data;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for this new `ExtendedBaseClass` to become the parent of all `ClassX`s ? At least in a new extended and re-exported version of them without the need to copy their internal code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the base code of the library, but only write around.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use an [importmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap) to remap './base_class' to your own BaseClass ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way for this new `ExtendedBaseClass` to become the parent of all `ClassX`s?

No.

An alternative might be to replace the one method directly on the base class:

```
import { BaseClass } from 'library';

const oneMethod = BaseClass.prototype.oneMethod;

Object.defineProperty(BaseClass.prototype, 'oneMethod', {
    value() {
         const data = oneMethod.call(this);
         // make additional things with data
         return data;
    },
});
```

Comment: That is indeed the alternative with the minimal change I can think of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do exactly what you're asking, but you could achieve the same result by extending each class individually.

```
ExtendedClassA extends ClassA {
  oneMethod() {
    // call a shared method if you need to reuse
  }
}

// ExtendedClassB, etc
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the upper prototype, but requires to apply it on all of them. I'll keep it in mind, thank you.

Comment: Correct, depending on the number of classes you may want something like what @Ry- suggested

Comment: Thinking again about it, the upper prototype change is in fact a good thing : for a case where `ClassA` already extends this method and it needs to have access to the new one through it's prototype. That it couldn't if it is implemented on `ExtendedClassA`